# Rigid non-algebraic manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, kahler-manifolds

The famous Kodaira problem asks: whether a compact Kähler manifold can always be deformed to a projective manifold? In order to provide a counterexample, one way is trying to construct a rigid compact Kähler manifold which is non-algebraic, then it can never be deformed to a algebraic one, thus provide a counterexample to Kodaira problem, do anyone have such kind of examples?

Comment: That is a good question, but I doubt there is a known counterexample.  I believe that Voisin's counterexamples to the Kodaira problem use blowing up of products of complex tori along special subvarieties (such as graphs of endomorphisms) that deform to families of complex tori (none of which is an Abelian variety by careful analysis of the cup product of the Hodge structures of the blowings up).  You might double-check her work: perhaps for very special collections of endomorphisms, the "complex torus with endomorphisms" is rigid.

Comment: @Jason Starr this is where my question originated from, I vaguely remember I have seen Voisin or someone else has mentioned such an example, but I forget where it is, and I'm looking for it.

Comment: Huybrechts' paper about Voisin's work says:Inspired by Voisin’s examples, Oguiso studies simply-connected compact Kähler manifolds of dimension ≥ 4 which are not projective, but rigid, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312515.pdf